# KDE Plasma Application Launcher is opening in the middle of the screen

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I'm not sure what I did, but for some reason, my application launcher menu now opens in the middle of the screen. It only happens when I select "application launcher" from the "show alternatives" menu.

I'm 100% sure I've selected "application launcher" and not "application dashboard". The behavior isn't like the dashboard. It is a smaller window, although much larger that the standard application launcher right panel.

[image: Application launcher weirdness in KDE Plasma 5]

Is this a setting or a bug? If it's a setting, I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome again to AskUbuntu, could you provide what kubuntu version are you using? Also QT and KDE Framework please?

Comment: Thanks! 

Kubuntu: 21.10
KDE Plasma: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2

Problem is there in both X11 and Wayland

Comment: Are you resuming a previous desktop session during shutdown/logout?

Comment: Could you refeer about what "middle of screen" means? sometimes, you can drag the launcher button to center by mistake, can you explain that pls?

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher - I added an image to the post. That is what I see when I click the application launcher button.

Comment: @Matthias - I'm new to KDE (long time Gnome user) but based on your comment about the launcher getting dragged around I clicked-and-held the launcher until the cursor changes to a "move" icon. I was then able to drag it back to the correct position. 

Now I just need to figure out how to change the categories back into text. The icons aren't bad, but I don't want to have it that way because I don't know how to change them back.

Comment: Right click on the application menu button, and click on configure. There should be an option to show text instead of icons in the categories.

Comment: Yep, there's the option to set only names (or just simply choose the "Application Menu" from menu alternatives). I'm on 5.24.2 KDE Plasma so the opions might be diff from yours.

Comment: PD: the window SS looks like a Market App than a menu LOL

Comment: I figured out how to resize the menu (super + right click and hold) and that auto-sized the icons. I couldn't find that option to change the categories back into text, though. The configure menu didn't have an option for it (although clearly there must be one somewhere, since I must have accidentally clicked it.)

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help everyone. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I have this solved with much help from the comments above.

KDE Plasma 5 treats the application launcher like a window, and it can be resized and moved.

- To move the application launcher: Super + Left-Click and hold
- To resize the application launcher: Super + Right-Click and hold
- To change the width of the left sidebar: Right-click the launcher icon and select "configure application launcher." Under layouts, make sure the "resizable sidebar" is selected. Then, hover over the sidebar border and drag to resize.

If you make the left sidebar thin enough, it will hide the text for the categories.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This worked for me, but it doesn't save the position. When I log out and back in, it is in the middle of the screen again.

Comment: @izzy - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this many times when I have installed a new launcher widget that pretends to be just an improved version of the default Application Launcher but has the bad habit of replacing the default one (because it has the same name and other setting).

So, go to `~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/` and delete the folders there, or probably just the one that has `kickoff` in the name.